# get column numbers that are equal to X

Tags: bash, awk, sed

imagine that I've the following string:

```
1 0 1 1 1
```

a simple implementation to get the column numbers that are equal to "1" is:

```
for column_number in $(seq 1 5); do
  zero_or_one=$(echo "1 0 1 1 1" | cut -d' ' -f$column_number)
  if [ "$zero_or_one" -eq "1" ]; then
    echo "$column_number"
  fi
done
```

however, as my strings tend to be very long, that loop takes ages (~ 1min).
is there any other way using for example awk, sed, ..., to get the column numbers that are equal to "1" or "0" ?

expected output if I'm looking for "1":

```
1
3
4
5
```

expected output if I'm looking for "0":

```
2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your question but this MAY be what you want:

```
$ awk -v RS=' ' '$0{print NR}' <<<'1 0 1 1 1'
1
3
4
5

$ awk -v RS=' ' '!$0{print NR}' <<<'1 0 1 1 1'
2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @ed-morton. this awk command already handles the "1" case, how can it be modified to handle either "1" or "0" ?

Comment: If I understand you, change `$0` to `!$0`. I added that case to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the kind of thing that you should awk for:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i == 1) print i }' <<<'1 0 1 1 1'
```

Loop through the fields, compare their value and print the ones that match.

---

That said, it's worth mentioning that you could improve the performance of your existing approach too:

```
while read -ra cols; do
    for (( i = 1; i <= ${#cols[@]}; ++i )); do
        [[ ${cols[i-1]} -eq 1 ]] && echo "$i"
    done
done <<<'1 0 1 1 1'
```

This uses native shell commands rather than executing separate processes to obtain each value, so it will be much quicker than your loop.

Note that the array is zero-indexed, so I've used `${cols[i-1]}` in order to obtain the same output.

Comment: wrt the shell loop, to be clear "much quicker" means much quicker than the original shell loop. It'll still be orders of magnitude slower than any reasonable awk solution. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: thanks @TomFenech. the awk answer is exactly what I was looking for.